# Setting the text of an Array of TextFields using an ActionListener

Tags: java, actionlistener

I'm trying to set the text of an array of TextFields using an ActionListener. I have my main class set up and my ActionListener class setup. I believe my problem is with setting up the ActionListener with multiple JTextFields generated with a for loop in my main class but I'm not sure. Here is my main class:
    package lab5.pkg2;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Panel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Lab52 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    Panel nPanel = new Panel();
    frame.add(nPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    Panel sPanel = new Panel();
    frame.add(sPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JTextField[] tf = new JTextField[10];
    for(int k = 0; k < tf.length; k++)
    {
        tf[k] = new JTextField(4);
        nPanel.add(tf[k]);
    }
    RandListener listen = new RandListener(tf);

    JButton bRand = new JButton("Randomize");
    bRand.setActionCommand("bRand");
    bRand.addActionListener(listen);
    sPanel.add(bRand);
    JButton bMaxMin = new JButton("Max, Min");
    bRand.setActionCommand("bMaxMin");
    bRand.addActionListener(listen);
    sPanel.add(bMaxMin);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}    
}
```

And here is my ActionListener class:

```
class RandListener implements ActionListener
{
private final JTextField[] tf = new JTextField[10]; 

public RandListener(JTextField[] tF)
{
    tf[0] = tF[0];
    tf[1] = tF[1];
    tf[2] = tF[2];
    tf[3] = tF[3];
    tf[4] = tF[4];
    tf[5] = tF[5];
    tf[6] = tF[6];
    tf[7] = tF[7];
    tf[8] = tF[8];
    tf[9] = tF[9];
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("bRand"))
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
        {
            Random rNum = new Random();
            tf[k].setText(rNum.toString());
        }
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("bMaxMin"))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to be working now ;) I've wrote some comments in the code with the things I've changed.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Panel;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Lab52 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    Panel nPanel = new Panel();
    frame.add(nPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    Panel sPanel = new Panel();
    frame.add(sPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JTextField[] tf = new JTextField[10];
    for(int k = 0; k < tf.length; k++)
    {
        tf[k] = new JTextField(4);
        nPanel.add(tf[k]);
    }
    RandListener listen = new RandListener(tf);

    JButton bRand = new JButton("Randomize");
    bRand.setActionCommand("bRand");
    bRand.addActionListener(listen);
    sPanel.add(bRand);

    JButton bMaxMin = new JButton("Max, Min");
    bMaxMin.setActionCommand("bMaxMin"); // These 2 lines were refering to bRand, not to bMaxMin
    bMaxMin.addActionListener(listen); 
    sPanel.add(bMaxMin);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}    
}
```

Your Listener class with some simplifications
- In the constructor
- In the if of the bRand I'm generating a random integer, I'm not sure if that is your goal.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class RandListener implements ActionListener
{
    private final JTextField[] tF;

    public RandListener(JTextField[] tF)
    {
        this.tF = tF; // I simplified your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("bRand"))
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < tF.length; k++)
            {
                Random rNum = new Random();
                tF[k].setText(rNum.nextInt() + ""); // Not sure if you wanted a random number..
            }
        }
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("bMaxMin"))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, It works! Thanks. Now is there a way to make the random integers only generate in the range from 0-100?